# Response Headers from Flickr as text/plain

Tags: javascript, content-type, flickr

I've been getting this error both on chrome and FF.

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.flickr.com/photos/72731305@N05/13905906938/".
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. The answers I find here on stackoverflow tell me that I need to change the server response... I don't have access to that.

I tried locally and on my domain and I get the same error.

My code:

```
(function(){

var flickr = (function(){

    var API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    var appendElements = function(dataSet){

        var photoSet = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];
        //var set= document.createTextNode('<img src="'+dataSet[0].id+'" />');
        var d;

        for (var i = 0;i<dataSet.length;i++){
            d = document.createElement('img');
            d.src= 'https://www.flickr.com/photos/'+dataSet[i].owner+'/'+dataSet[i].id+'/';
            photoSet.appendChild(d);
        }


    }

    return {
        getPhotos: function(searchQuery){
            var url =  'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key='+ API_KEY+'&text='+searchQuery+'&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&per_page=15',
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","image/jpeg");

            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText).photos.photo;
                    appendElements(response);
                }
            }

            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();


        }

    }

})();

var input = document.getElementById('test');

input.addEventListener("submit",function(event){

    flickr.getPhotos(this.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
    event.preventDefault();
},false);
})();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this causing you a problem?

Comment: @steven images I try to get from flickr are not rendered by the browser.